# How to add comment to selected text in MS Word using Office App?

Tags: javascript, office365api, office365-apps, office365-restapi, office-app

I am new in Office App development. I want to add comment to selected text on  button click. I can get selected text using following code but I don't know how to add comment in selected text.

Code:Home.js

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    // The initialize function must be run each time a new page is loaded
    Office.initialize = function (reason) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            app.initialize();

            $('#get-data-from-selection').click(getDataFromSelection);
        });
    };

    // Reads data from current document selection and displays a notification
    function getDataFromSelection() {
        Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync(Office.CoercionType.Text,
            function (result) {
                if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                    app.showNotification('The selected text is:', '"' + result.value + '"');
                } else {
                    app.showNotification('Error:', result.error.message);
                }
            }
        );
    }
})();
```

SS:
[image]

Can anybody please guide me about to add comment in selected text?

Answer (score 0):

I can use the [setSelectedDataAsync](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.setselecteddataasync) method with the options.
https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/customxmlnodetype-enumeration

```
   Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync("my comment", {CustomXMLNodeType: Office.Office.CustomXMLNodeType.NodeComment}
function (asyncResult) {
    var error = asyncResult.error;
    if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed){
        console.log(error.name + ": " + error.message);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I will surely try this. That will be really great if this solution works. Can I add comments in HTML format? i.e <b>Hello World!</b> should add comment in bold.

Answer (score 0):

```
const commentTitle = "Hello Comment";
let comment = context.document.getSelection().insertComment(commentTitle);
await context.sync();
```

Comment: Hey there, code-only answers are okay but it would be more helpful if you would add a bit of explanation. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer